# Automatically include my Solana program in local validator?

Tags: solana-program, solana-test-validator, local-cluster

Is it possible to start a local validator with my Solana program already deployed?

Or do I have to do 2 separate commands? One first starting the validator, another for deploying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example scenario: Say you wanted to load the spl stake-pool program and you had its shared-object file saved at fixtures/spl-stake-pool.so.

If you're running tests with anchor then adding:

```
[[test.genesis]]
address = "SPoo1Ku8WFXoNDMHPsrGSTSG1Y47rzgn41SLUNakuHy"
program = "fixtures/spl_stake_pool.so"
```

to your Anchor.toml file would load the program under the specified address.

If not then:

```
solana-test-validator --bpf-program SPoo1Ku8WFXoNDMHPsrGSTSG1Y47rzgn41SLUNakuHy fixtures/spl_stake_pool.so"
```

would do the same.

Note: The --bpf-program flag also accepts a keypair path as its first argument. So instead of a pubkey like "SPoo1..", you can specify `fixtures/address-kp.json` and solana-test-validator will retrieve the address from it. The anchor config file should likely allow that also